# SOC7 abend while comparing fields

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I am getting abend while comparing 2 fields
They are defined as:

```
01 A   PIC S9(8) COMP VALUE 0.
01 B   PIC S9(5) COMP-3.
```

The statement which is going into abend is:

```
PERFORM VARYING A FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL A > B
```

THIS statement is in another loop and Value of B IS increased there.  For first two iterations the value of B is correct. And for 3 rd iteration , The value of B Displayed is non numeric.

Could you please suggest what can be done here?

Comment: Look at what is updating B's storage.  The S0C7 does not happen because everything is ok.  btw why did you make B packed-decimal ?  If it only serves for the comparison with A it's better to have both the same format (both binary or both packed-decimal).

Comment: As @ErwinSmout said, you need to find what is modifying B.  Note, that if B is part of a redefines, it could be another value that is actually being modified.

Comment: SOC7 means that a numeric operation was attempted on non-numeric data. So at some point, one of the variables has non-numeric data in it.

Comment: Hi all,Thank you for suggestions. I changed format of both fields to same and it worked.

Comment: If its working that's awesome.  The problem is it should have been working all along :)   If you have an overlay problem you simply masked it and didn't solve it.  Caveat emptor.

Answer (score 0):

We have this kind of scenario where we need to compare 2 different numeric fields & sometimes non-numeric data creeps in from external systems. What we did is redefined the fields with an `PIC X(n)` equivalent to the byte size & kept a `NUMERIC` check on the `IF` statements. Some thing like this -

```
    IF  WS-FIELD1 NUMERIC AND WS-FIELD2 NUMERIC
        IF WS-FIELD1 NOT = WS-FIELD2
***        both fields are numeric but not equal
        ELSE
***        both fields are numeric & equal
        END-IF
    ELSE
        IF WS-FIELD1-X NOT = WS-FIELD2-X
***        both fields are non-numeric & not equal
        ELSE
***        both fields are non-numeric but equal
        END-IF
    END-IF
```

I'm not sure why you are using `PERFORM VARYING` for a numeric field but I'm sure you can fit it somewhere in the above code.